# Outlook took 30GB of hard drive, how to remove local content?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office, microsoft-outlook-2013, disk-space

My computer only has 120GB of space, so I carefully manage how much space programs take up. yesterday I installed Outlook 2013 and synced with it 2 email accounts.

Today, I have only 2GB left on my hard drive compared to the 32GB I had last night. I imagine Outlook has taken up all that space.

What do I do to make Outlook only store on my computer mail from the past e.g. 1 week?

Comment: You could consider IMAP? Or in Outlook and POP3, only download N amount of emails from the server. I don't have it to test, but in the Account Settings, click on the account and go to More settings, then the advanced tab. I think you can set the amount/time there (and to not delete it off server)

Comment: But if you're storage space limited, would you not be better off using a web client instead?

Answer (score 0):

1. Considering you've got such a large mailbox you could use the
   outlook web app
2. Remove the app data
       (C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Outlook), slim down your mailbox and re-sync.
3. Set a mail retention policy to either archive or delete your files, see here: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Retention-and-archive-policies-in-Outlook-Web-App-465372e4-e16b-47db-bee0-aba44799085e

Comment: Well, I want the mail to stay available online. I just don't want it to be stored on my computer. Won't a retention policy physically delete mail?

Comment: You could archive the older mail into a folder hosted on your mail server then set that folder to be never synced. But yes, a retention policy will delete your mail.